# pulling and yanking together?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The sentence:

> Suddenly two police officers started **pulling and yanking** (at) the scaffolding trying to shake the protester off it.

Info:

The two police officers are standing at the foot of the scaffolding trying with all their force to shake the protester, who stands on top of it, off of it.

Questions:

Are "pulling and yanking" natural together or is there a more natural combination? Also, is it the best combination if I want it to sound as forceful as possible?

Answer (score 1):

- "Pulling" means to exert force on something in the direction of oneself.
- "Yanking" means to *suddenly* pull something, with a jerk.

Although they are slightly different, it seems odd to use them together as you have, because you can only do one or the other. "Yanking at" would suggest repeatedly doing so, and this would suggest using more force than simply pulling".

However, you said you are trying to describe them "shaking" someone down. Why not just use the word "shaking"? Shaking would imply them alternatively *pushing and pulling*, which you could also say.

Comment: I prefer to avoid using "shaking" to avoid repetition and also because I don't think it sounds forceful enough. But could I use "pushing and pulling"?

Comment: @user118626 you need both actions to shake something, so, yes. "pushing and pulling at the scaffolding to shake the protestor off it"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yank), yank has two meanings:

> 1. to pull something forcefully with a quick movement
> 2. to suddenly remove someone or something

To my mind, the movement is the most important part of yanking, and I wouldn't expect it to return to its normal position. So you could yank scaffolding down (pull the whole lot over) but if you are simply pulling it and it returns to its normal position after each pull, then I don't think that yanking is the right word.

As others have said, shaking is probably the best term to use. There is no limit to the amount of force used in a shake... an earthquake where buildings are falling down can be called shaking.